# Text Fields and Spinners in Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, spinner, textfield

How do i set a text field in Eclipse to work in conjunction with an item selected in a Spinner? EXAMPLE- If the user selects the second item (out of lets say 3 in the drop down menu) i want them to be able to use the text field to the fight of the spinner to set a value to that item selected. Think of it like a translation tool. If the person selects English out of the menu of languages and then types in an english word (in the text field) i want it to be able to CONVERT that to whatever they chose in the second spinner (Spanish) once they hit the "convert" button.

I apologize if this question seems more in need of a java/eclipse lesson then code help, but i appreciate any help at all :)

MainActivity

```
package com.overworldinnovations.datatool;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.os.Build;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {


private Spinner spinner1, spinner2;
private Button buttonConvert;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    addItemsOnSpinner2();
    addListenerOnButton();
    addListenerOnSpinnerItemSelection();

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();   
    }
}

public void addItemsOnSpinner2() {

    spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
    //List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
    spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new CustomOnItemSelectedListener());

    /*list.add("list 1");
    list.add("list 2");
    list.add("list 3");
    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner2.setAdapter(dataAdapter);*/
  }

public void addListenerOnSpinnerItemSelection() {
    spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new CustomOnItemSelectedListener());
  }

public void addListenerOnButton() {

    spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
    buttonConvert = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonConvert);

    buttonConvert.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {

        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
        "OnClickListener : " + 
                "\nSpinner 1 : "+ String.valueOf(spinner1.getSelectedItem()) + 
                "\nSpinner 2 : "+ String.valueOf(spinner2.getSelectedItem()),
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }

    });
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                false);
        return rootView;
    }
}

}
```

activity_main

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.overworldinnovations.datatool.MainActivity"
tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonConvert"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
    android:text="Convert" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Please Select A Data Type To Be Converted"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/spinner1"
    android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
    android:entries="@array/type_arrays"
    android:prompt="@string/data_prompt" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
    android:entries="@array/type_arrays"
    android:prompt="@string/data_prompt" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/spinner2"
    android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="numberSigned" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/spinner1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="numberSigned" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

strings

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

<string name="app_name">Data Tool</string>
<string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
<string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
<string name="convert">Convert</string>
<string name="data_tool_is_an_application_that_converts_binary_to_decimal_d">Data Tool is an application that converts Binary to Decimal :D</string>
<string name ="data_prompt">Choose a data type</string>

<string-array name = "type_arrays">
    <item >Decimal</item>
    <item >Binary</item>
    <item >Hexidecimal</item>
</string-array>
</resources>
```

CustomOnItemSelectedListener

```
package com.overworldinnovations.datatool;

import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.Toast;

 public class CustomOnItemSelectedListener implements OnItemSelectedListener {

  public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos,long id) {
    Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), 
        "OnItemSelectedListener : " + parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString(),
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }

   @Override
   public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   }

}
```

Comment: Show the code you have written so far to achieve this. We can help you fix the problems from there.

Comment: @Takendarkk there the code i have so far! Thanks for the reply and concern :)

Comment: Your code and acitivity.xml is not matching, please share the completed and add more detail where you have the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Well, i cannot tell you about your conversion thingy but i will tell you how to listen to do something based on a selected spinner entry and how to manipulate textfields. The rest you have to code :-)

Here comes a class that implements a spinner, and does something based on the selected option in the spinner. It can be made very different too but this should explain things easy.

```
public  class MyClass extends Fragment implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

// Your Spinner
public Spinner spinner;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab2, container, false);

    // Customize from here
    final TextView textview = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
    final Button button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_calculate);

    setSpinnerContent( view );

    // attach an OnClickListener
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {

            Integer selectedOption = spinner.getSelectedItemPosition();


                if (selectedOption==0) {

                    myString = "Option 1 selected";
                }
                if (selectedOption==1) {

                    myString = "Option 2 selected";
                }
                if (selectedOption==2) {

                    myString = "Option 3 selected";
                }

            textview.setText(myString);
            }


        }
    );
    return view;
}
private void setSpinnerContent( View view )
{
    spinner = (Spinner) view.findViewById( R.id.spinner );
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(), R.array.planets_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter( adapter );

}


public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) { // ItemsSelected

    //An alternate way to listen to the selected items
}

public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
    // Another interface callback
}
```

}

The spinner gets content from an String XML resource like this:

```
<string-array name="planets_array">
    <item>Euro</item>
    <item>US-Dollar</item>
    <item>Yen</item>
</string-array>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            String val = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();//Getting Value of Selected Item
            txtPerc.setText(val);//TextView
        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

Do Something Like This.. And please Clear Your Question.
Hope Its Help..